# How to Center an Image matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, offset

I have a graph in matplotlib that I want to overlay an image onto. Currently I am doing so using OffsetImage:

```
team_logo = (os.getcwd() + "\Team_Logos"'\\' + data['posteam'].iloc[0] + '.png')
team_logo = plt.imread(team_logo)
team_logo = OffsetImage(team_logo, zoom=0.50)
team_logo.set_offset((2800, 2800))
ax.add_artist(team_logo)
```

But instead of the `team_logo.set_offset((2800, 2800))` line, I would like to have the image be centered. I have images of varying sizes that I want to be using at different times, so manually changing the `((2800,2800)` to different coordinates for each figure I create is not a good solution. I am also using `plt.savefig()` with `dpi=400` for my final image.

The actual graph itself is always a 120 by 53.3 graph (x by y), but for some reason OffsetImage has the overlaid image show up differently in plt.show() than in plt.savefig(), so I can't just use `((60,26.65))`.

Does anyone know if there is a way for me to center my image over my plot that is saved to an image? I don't have to use OffsetBox, if there is a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html), the easiest is probably to use an AnnotationBbox:

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

img = plt.imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Ada_Lovelace_color.svg/200px-Ada_Lovelace_color.svg.png', format='png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.4)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0.5, 0.5), xycoords='axes fraction',
                    bboxprops={'lw':0})

ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

[image]